# Display a tally (in varying bases)

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, counting

Tallying is a simple counting system that works in base 5. There are various different tallying systems used around the world, but the one that is used in most English-speaking countries is perhaps the most simple - count units by marking vertical lines, then for each 5th mark put a horizontal line through the previous collection of four. This clusters the tally marks in groups of 5 (and makes them easier to quickly count).

You are going to write a program that displays tally marks up to a given value. But, tallying in only base 5 is boring! Therefore, your program should also be able to display tallies in different bases.

### Input

The input will be **either one or two non-negative integer values** separated by a comma (e.g. `9` or `8,4`). The first number is the value that should be displayed by the tally. The second value is the base of the tally. **If the second value is not given, use base 5**.

### Output

The output will be the inputted value represented as ASCII art tally marks. Here are some examples you can test your program against - your output should match them exactly!

Input: `12` or `12,5`

```
 | | | |   | | | |   | |
-+-+-+-+- -+-+-+-+-  | |
 | | | |   | | | |   | |
```

Input: `7,3`

```
 | |   | |   |
-+-+- -+-+-  |
 | |   | |   |
```

Input: `4,2`

```
 |   |
-+- -+-
 |   |
```

Input: `6,1` or `6,10` (notice the leading spaces)

```
 | | | | | |
 | | | | | |
 | | | | | |
```

Note also that base 1 is intended to be inconsistent - only vertical lines should be used.

If either of the inputted values is 0, there should be **no output whatsoever** (and your program should end gracefully).

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest correct implementation (in bytes) wins.
- Input/output can be in any suitable medium (e.g. stdin/stdout, file...).
- Input can be in the form of multiple command-line arguments or separated by spaces, etc. if it is more suitable for your target language.
- Trailing newlines are allowed in the output. Trailing spaces are not. This rule only applies when there is an output (i.e. not when the inputted value is 0).
- Your code must default to base 5 when no base is input.

Comment: Shouldn't the output of `6,1` look more like `-+- -+- -+- -+- -+- -+-`?

Comment: If you state "The input will be either one or two positive integer values separated by a comma (e.g. 9 or 8,4)." then we should be able to take that as a given, and not have to worry about "Your program should be robust - you should validate the input..." beyond handling one or two numbers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor `-+-` would represent two, because there's a vertical line and a horizontal score through it. Base 1 would only have vertical lines. @AndoDaan ammended.

Comment: Ok, `--- --- --- --- --- ---` then. For consistency with the other bases you should be putting a horizontal strike through `b-1` vertical lines. If it's intended to be inconsistent you should state that explicitly.

Comment: I've done that. Sorry, I thought it was implied.

Comment: is there any leeway in the input format (comma-separated values are much less helpful than two separate command-line arguments, or even just space-separated standard input)?

Comment: Yes, I'll add this to the rules.

Comment: Are trailing newlines allowed?

Comment: Yes, added. I need to find more ways of surpassing the 15 character minimum...

Comment: But are trailing newlines allowed if ```n==0```? Or does the "n=0->no-output" rule overrule the trailing-newline rule?

Comment: The no output rule overrides it. Ideally your program will spot that `n = 0` and exit before any printing is done (or just skip it altogether).

Comment: Is there a maximum value for the numbers? Can I assume they're less than two billion?

Comment: I said "positive integer", so I guess the maximum depends on your implementation. I'm not evil enough to want to test any inputs that high though :^)

Comment: @ipi I was about to abuse a mistake you made when I decided I'd better correct your post instead. Zero is not "positive" yet it is a valid input, so I changed it to say "non-negative".

Comment: With regard to the "no trailing spaces" rule, does this forbid trailing spaces at the end each of the 3 lines of output, or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: If input is two numbers separated with a comma, like `7,2`, can I implement this as receiving input between the parentheses of a function call like `f(7,2)`?

Comment: Can we assume 2¹⁵ - 1 as an upper limit for the numbers you test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CJam *103* *85* **72** characters

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/.

### original

```
q","/(i:A\_,{~i}{;5}?:B_@*{(_{" |"*S"l"++AB/*AB%}{;MA}?\:J" |l""-+ "er\" |"*N+_J\+@2$+@J\+++"l"Ser}{;}?
```

Works by defining one set of tallys with spaces, lines and an l for spaces that should remain spaces.  Then takes advantage of er (tranliteration) function to make the second line.  Most inefficient part is dealing with the 1 and 0 special cases.  Will edit as I improve it.  Tip I took too long to realize: as the second input being 1 is the same as infinity or the first input +1, redefining it when it is equal to 1 saves alot of work.

### most improved so far with comma delimited

```
l",":G/(i:A\_5a?~i:B_@*{(_" |":K*\{SG++AB/*AB%}{A}?\_KG+"-+ "er[\GSer_@@M]\K*N+*}{;}?
```

### most improved so far with space delimited input

Naturally as CJam is really designed for space delimited input. Placing the input at 20 3  instead of 20,3 is a huge benefit.

```
ri:Aq_5s?S-i(_)A)?:B*{B(" |":K*STs++ABmd@@*_K"-+"er[\_@@M]\K*N+*TsSer}M?
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 - <s>111 108 119 144 140 136 135</s> 134 - [Try it](http://ideone.com/nA1khZ)

Ok, let's give it a try:

```
i=input()
n,b=[(i,5),i][i>[]]
o=b-1
a=[n,n%b][b>1]*' |'
m=(b>1)*n/b
s=(' |'*o+'  ')*m+a
print(s+'\n'+('-+'*o+'- ')*m+a+'\n'+s)*(b*n>0)
```

**Edit:** I've overlooked that there should be no output if `n==0` or `b==0`. This costs me 11 characters. :(

**Edit:** Ok, after fixing the second issue mentioned in the comments my solution basically converged to the one from BeetDemGuise.

Comment: This prints newlines when either of the inputs (or both) are zero which according the challenge is undesired. Also, what if only one number is input into the program?

Comment: This fails when the second value is omitted (`b` should be 5 in this case). I'll make it more clear in the question. Edit: oh, never mind, you fixed it just as I made this comment!

Comment: Which Python is this?

Comment: It's Python 2.7.8. - Oh, there was a tiny mistake at the very end...

Comment: If it's Python 2.x couldn't you save one more character by using `n/b`instead of `n//b`?

Comment: Hey, you're right! I always forget that Python does integer division by default, since the Spyder command line does not: ```3/2``` yields ```1.5```.

Comment: If you try this with large numbers then the result looks sloppy. [Example](http://ideone.com/FeXpfk)

Comment: I believe this answer will leave trailing spaces for input "5".

Comment: @VisualMelon: No, I don't think so. You can [try it here](http://ideone.com/nA1khZ).

Comment: @G_Wilson: That behavior was not clearly specified and I guess every answer here has its problems for large numbers. For a sufficiently wide terminal window it'll work. ;)

Comment: @Falko IDEOne refuses to work for me, but I asked a friend to test it was printing 5 trailing spaces for input five (2 on the first line, one on the next, two on the last line (padded to the 2*n char, as such)). I may be mis-interpreted what the OP meant by trailing spaces, I'll ask him to clarify in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash, <del>239 228 199 189</del> 188

Here's my attempt, it could be golfed a lot.

Note: the second line does not subtract 5 from 2, it sets a [default value](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) if `$2` is empty!

```bsh
n=$1
b=${2-5}
((n<1&b<1))&&exit
while ((n>b&b>1));do
n=$[n-b]
x+=\
y+=-
for i in `seq $[b-1]`;{
x+='| '
y+=+-
}
x+=\
y+=\
done
for j in `seq $n`;{
x+=' |'
y+=' |'
}
echo -e "$x\n$y\n$x"
```

Comment: Does `{1..$n}` work instead of `\`seq $n\``?

Comment: @FUZxxl unfortunately not, `h=8;echo {1..$h}` outputs `{1..8}`

Comment: That's not good.

Answer (score 3):

### Python - <s>171</s> 143

```
i=input();t,b=i if[0]<i else(i,5);b=[b,t+1][b==1];l,d,m,o=' |',t/b,t%b,b-1;r=(l*o+'  ')*d+l*m
if t*b>0:print r,'\n',('-+'*o+'- ')*d+l*m,'\n',r
```

The program is pretty straight-forward:

- Get the input and try to unpack into `t,b`. If that fails, simply assign the correct values.
- If the base was `1`, change its value to something that can handle all vertical lines easily (`t+1`).
- Set some variables and create the bottom and top sections of the tallies.
- Print out the tallies if both `t` and `b` are non-zero.

**EDIT 1:** Use the `input` function instead of `raw_input` after some playing around.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to Falko for pointing out a small bug with my non-zero checking. Now our code is basically identical, less some variable names and some small logic.

**EDIT 3:** Thanks to [how Python compares sequences and different types](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types), we can compare `i` to a `list` to get a shorter version of our `try...except` block.

Here is the ungolfed version:

```
i=input()

# If True, `i` must be a list
if [0]<i:
    t,b=i
# Otherwise, we know its a number (since `list` comes after `int` lexicographically.)
else:
    b=5
    t=i

b = b if b==1 else t+1
l=' |'
d=t/b
m=t%b
o=b-1

r=(l*o+'  ')*d+l*m
if t and b:
    print r,'\n',('-+'*o+'- ')*d+l*m,'\n',r
```

Comment: I think ```t&b``` is ```False``` for 10,5. Otherwise our solutions are converging! ;)

Comment: @Falko You are right on both counts! You know what they say about great minds.

Comment: It'd be really great if we could find a short way to test if ```i``` is scalar or a list. Then we could drop the ```try ... except``` monster.

Comment: @Falko I think I found a 1byte-better check. A `list` is always greater than an int. Also, `list`s are compared in lexicographical order. So if we compare `[0]<i` this will always return `False` if `i` is a number and `True` if `i` is a list (with a non-zero first element).

Comment: Great! I further shortened your approach. Nice teamwork! :)

Comment: I have not been able to test this (can't get IDEOne to work and I don't have Python 2) but it would appear to me that this will print a trailing space in the 2nd line if it ends "- ", am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

## C - 193

I'm so sorry. Dealing with the special case for 1 was a bit of a bad hack so I guess this could be golfed more with a better approach. Also, this code includes a new line at the beginning of the output, so if this is not allowed, please let me know.

Of course, very ugly-looking defines always help :)

Character count includes only necessary spaces and new lines.

```c
#define P printf(
#define L P" |")
#define A P"\n");for(i=0;i<a;)b==1?i++,L:i++&&i%b==0?P
i;
main(a,b)
{
    scanf("%d,%d",&a,&b)<2?b=5:!b?a=0:a;
    if(a){
    A"  "):L;
    A"- "):a%b&&i>a/b*b?L:P"-+");
    A"  "):L;}
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to print newlines when one of the values is zero. This is explictly disallowed. Your solution is not conforming.

Comment: @FUZxxl You're right, I missed that! This bad quick fix will have to do for now. I hope I have time soon to find a better way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can save a few characters by replacing `printf` with `puts`, and replacing `return` with a ternary operator.

Comment: @millinon The problem with `puts` is that it adds a new line every time :(. And for the ternary operator, it is not possible to add `return`s or `for`s inside them!. Your comment did give me the idea to save a few more characters very easily by removing the `return` though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 343

```
class C{public static void main(String[]a){long n=new Long(a[0])+1,b=a.length>1?new Long(a[1]):5;if(b>0){if(b<2)b=(int)2e9;int i;for(i=1;i<n;i++)p(i%b>0?" |":"  ");p("\n");for(i=1;i<n-n%b;i++)p(i%b>0?"-+":"- ");if(n>b)p("- ");for(i=1;i<n%b;i++)p(" |");p("\n");for(i=1;i<n;i++)p(i%b>0?" |":"  ");}}static void p(String s){System.out.print(s);}}
```

Less golfed:

```
class C {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    long n=new Long(a[0])+1, b=a.length>1 ? new Long(a[1]) : 5;
    if(b>0) {
      if(b<2) b=(int)2e9; // if the base is 1, pretend the base is 2 billion
      int i;
      for(i=1;i<n;i++) p(i%b>0 ? " |" : "  ");
      p("\n");
      for(i=1;i<n-n%b;i++) p(i%b>0 ? "-+" : "- ");
      if(n>b) p("- ");
      for(i=1;i<n%b;i++) p(" |");
      p("\n");
      for(i=1;i<n;i++) p(i%b>0 ? " |" : "  ");
    }
  }
  static void p(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can save a few by making `i` a `long` so you don't have to declare it separately. A few more by doing `i++%b>0` in your loops instead of incrementing it separately (and `i++<n%b` in the third loop). Another one by using `b=b<2?(int)2e9:b`.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - <del>167</del> <del>165</del> 156

```
my($n,$b)=($ARGV[0]=~/(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?/,5);print$b>1?map{join(" ",($_ x($b-1))x int($1/$b)," | "x($1%$b))."\n"}(" | ","-+-"," | "):join" ",("---")x$1if$1*$b
```

### ungolfed

```
my($n,$b) = ($ARGV[0] =~ /(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?/, 5);
print($b>1 ?
    map{ 
        join(" ",($_ x ($b-1)) x int($1/$b)," | " x ($1%$b))."\n"
    } (" | ","-+-"," | ") :
    join " ", ("---") x $1
) if $1 * $b
```

Comment: displays horizontal lines instead of vertical ones for base 1 :(

Comment: @chineseperlgoth yes, that's one of the requirements. Please read comments on Q.

Answer (score 2):

### C# 271bytes

Not the shortest, I couldn't golf the input reading due to it needing to accept 0 as an input.

```c#
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var L=C.ReadLine().Split(',');int t=int.Parse(L[0]),f=L.Length>1?int.Parse(L[1]):5,r=3,i;for(var R="";t*f>0&r-->0;C.WriteLine(R.TrimEnd()))for(R="",i=0;i<t;R+=r==1&i++<t-t%f?(i%f<1?"- ":"-|"):i%f<1?"  ":" |")f+=f<2?t:0;}}
```

Formatted code:

```c#
using C=System.Console;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var L=C.ReadLine().Split(',');
        int t=int.Parse(L[0]),f=L.Length>1?int.Parse(L[1]):5,r=3,i;

        for(var R="";t*f>0&r-->0;C.WriteLine(R.TrimEnd()))
            for(R="",i=0;i<t;R+=r==1&i++<t-t%f?(i%f<1?"- ":"-|"):i%f<1?"  ":" |")
                f+=f<2?t:0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua - <s>219</s> 203 bytes

I went for the make d copies of b copies of "|", then add r copies of "|" at the end. I feel like maybe I should have gone with the 'tally up' the "|"s to the string one at a time.

```
l=' |'s=string.rep _,_,a,b=io.read():find'(%d+)%D*(%d*)'b=tonumber(b)or 5 d=(a-a%b)/b f=b>1 and s(s(l,b-1)..'  ',d)g=b>1 and s(s('-+',b-1)..'- ',d)r=b>1 and a%b or a e=s(l,r)..'\n'print(f..e..g..e..f..e)
```

ungolfed:

```
l=' |'          --the base string
s=string.rep    --string.rep will be used a lot, so best shorten it

_,_,a,b=io.read():find'(%d+)%D*(%d*)' --reads a,b I'm probably way of the mark with this one

b=tonumber(b)or 5

d=(a-a%b)/b -- shorter than math.floor(a/b), d equal the vertical mark

f=b>1 and s(s(l,b-1)..'  ',d) or '' --creates d multiples of b multiples of "|" more or less
g=b>1 and s(s('-+',b-1)..'- ',d)or''--same as above but with the middle "-+-"

r=b>1 and a%b or a --idk maybe i should set r before d(a- a%b )/b

e=s(l,r)..'\n'  -- makes the remainder string, notice that if b==1  then e will output all the "|" 

print(f..e..g..e..f..e) -- here's where the real magic happens!
```

Sample:

```
c:\Programming\AnarchyGolfMine>lua test.lua
13,5
 | | | |   | | | |   | | |
-+-+-+-+- -+-+-+-+-  | | |
 | | | |   | | | |   | | |


c:\Programming\AnarchyGolfMine>lua test.lua
6,2
 |   |   |
-+- -+- -+-
 |   |   |


c:\Programming\AnarchyGolfMine>lua test.lua
18,1
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
```

Comment: Could you post a sligthly more readable and ungolfed version? Golfing in Lua looks interesting!

Comment: @Alessandro done. And thanks, it made find a couple things I missed.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (193)

This might be overly complex.

```js
s=prompt().split(",");a=+s[0];b=s[1];b=b?+b:5;o=b>1;v=" | ";q=w="";for(g=~~(a/b),c=o?a-g:a;g+1;g--,q+=" ",w+=" ")for(i=o;c&&i<b;i++)c--,q+=v,w+=g&&o?"-+-":v;if(a&&b)console.log(q+'\n'+w+'\n'+q)
```

---

**Commented version**

```js
s=prompt().split(",");
a=+s[0];
b=s[1];
b=b?+b:5;   // convert b to int and default to 5
o=b>1;      // special handling for b0 and b1
v=" | ";
q=w="";
// calculate number of lines and number of groups
for(g=~~(a/b),c=o?a-g:a;g+1;g--,q+=" ",w+=" ")
    for(i=o;c&&i<b;i++)
        c--,  // decrease line count
        q+=v,
        w+=g&&o?"-+-":v; // use " | " for last group and "-+-" for others
if(a&&b) // handle b0
    console.log(q+'\n'+w+'\n'+q)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <s>127</s> <s>123</s> 122

Just sneaking in with a slightly shorter python version.

edit: Fixed 0 not printing nothing and rejigger, ended up the same length

```
k=input()
k=i,j=((k,5),k)[k>[]]
for m in[' |','-+',' |']*all(k):
 print(m*(j-1)+m[0]+' ')*(i/j*(j>1))+' |'*(i%(j+(j<2)*i))
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (207 characters)

The newline right before `exit` is for legibility only.

```
#define P printf(
#define t(v)for(a=c;b<=a;a-=b)a-c&&P" "),P v+1),q(b,v);q(a," |");P"\n");
q(n,c){while(n--)P c);}a;b;c;main(){scanf("%d,%d",&c,&b)<2?b=5:0;b&&c||
exit();b==1?b=32767:0;t("| ")t("+-")t("| ")}
```

`scanf` usage shamelessy stolen from Allbeert. Notice that this solution does not compile with gcc as it tries to enforce a nonexistant prototype for `exit`. Compile with a working C compiler like `tcc`. Also, this function may or may not work on 64 bit platforms. Use with care.

Here is the original ungolfed implementation this is based on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void
tally_line(int base, int count, const char *str)
{
     int follower = 0, i;

     /* full tallies first */
     for (; count >= base; count -= base) {
          if (follower++)
               putchar(' ');

          /* only print second character */
          printf(str + 1);

          for (i = 0; i < base; i++)
               printf(str);
     }

     /* partial tally */
     for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
          printf(" |");

     /* newline */
     puts("");
}

extern int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     int base, count;

     /* do away with program name */
     count = atoi(*++argv);

     base = argc - 3 ? 5 : atoi(*++argv);

     /* remove 0 later */
     base | count || exit(0);

     /* a crossed-out tally never appears for large numbers */
     if (base == 1)
          base = 32767;

     tally_line(base, count, "| ");
     tally_line(base, count, "+-");
     tally_line(base, count, "| ");

     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>134</s> <s>126</s> <s>123</s> 114 bytes

```python
lambda i,j=5,a=" |":"\n".join(("",(a*~-j+"  ","-+"*~-j+"- ")[x%2]*(i/j))[j>1]+a*(i,i%j)[j>1]for x in(0,1,2)if i*j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7LCoMwEEX3/YphQMjo2CZprVCwP6IuUoo0oVURFxZKf90GxMemu3NPyL3TvvtHU@uxyorxaV63uwHLLkvYZAgfvGBR4941thYCkYUJv7GLEAAZ4winFANSPgS6DIU9OKLcXVUZGZ/YBm6KVdPBAL5GsmJNtgIbOhrbztY9oNJ@BiKohNIEu8VysnpOaH5I@Th7jwTLjxMvRR7XpjOr2XukjZYbLzcDch1YteR01h79LsD471b4AQ)

Old question I know but fun to have a go at anyway. Chance to try out a few tricks I've learned since joining.